# How can the D2C entry of plone be used as input for another form with extra input fields?

Tags: python, plone, ploneformgen

I create an input form using ploneformgen, with 2 input fields and 1 file field. After saving the input using Save data to Content adapter, I trigger a rule which moves it to another form folder / folder. This data should be editable along with **new input fields** in the new folder. A case where in the previous form these input fields are not available at all.
If data is saved now it should have, the entry as 1 single record, with all the field attributes including the new field inputs. **OR**
Atleast how can I get a selection box populated with the saved data to content entry with 'nice ids' as the selection string in the new form dynamically ?

Main idea is to **relate** the data submitted by the 2 forms and trigger different workflows.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are really pushing the boundaries of PloneFormGen, and are (close to) exceeding them. Perhaps you should consider using z3c.form forms instead, and use full python views to handle your complex requirements?

Comment: You may be able to do an override vocabulary and query the catalog for the values. I think it's hard to give a specific answer for this though.